# ContentProvider and Listview - Data Not Updating After Content Changes

Tags: android, listview, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

I have a listview on 1st Activity (uses custom CursorAdapter, CursorLoader and ContentProvider) and when user click on list row it opens another 2nd Activity where user can DELETE this item. When he choose DELETE, row in table in database is deleted (with ContentProvider) and 2nd Activity finish(). But 1st Activity still shows old content.

I thought that as ContentProvider carry and CursorLoader get every DB updates, deletes and insertions my listview on 1st Activity should show the new list without that deleted row. But it is still here.

Before, I get this changes by requery() method or with other methods that pass to  CursorAdapter  and ListView in onRestart() that data is changed.

I confused what I should do to show in ListView in 1st Activity only actual data after 
deletion?

May be I should use

```
loaderManager.restartLoader(LOADER_ID, null, mCallbacks);
```

? in onRestart(), but why?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem. I am in teh sam trouble.

Answer (score 1):

When underlying data changes, the data provided to your ListView by your ContentProvider won't automatically just update.  You  need to notify the application wide ContentResolver that data for one of your registered contentProviders has changed.

You do this by sending out a notification through the ContentResolver to the appropriate URI of the ContentProvider in question.  The line of code looks like this:

```
getContentResolver().notifyChange(MY_URI, null);
```

You can add this to your 2nd activity once the delete occurs. Obviously, you need to update the MY_URI to the appropriate URI to your content provider. If you've implemented your LoaderManager correctly, you'll see the ListView data refresh with the new data.

Comment: This would work if data was changed from the same activiy where listview resides. But if data is change in another activity via  content provider it does not work. Method notifyChange() just does not refreshes listview. very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I used this in my similar case:

```
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
```